# How many GPS-Satellites are needed for time synchronization without positioning

Tags: gps, time

Is it possible to do time synchronization without positioning with only 1 GPS satellite?

If not, how many satellites do i need for time synchronization without positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the situation, **if the user's location is unknown**, at least **four satellites** need to be used to achieve positioning and timing measurements, and **if the exact location of the user is known**, the timing synchronization can be achieved using data from a **single satellite**.